# How to move a search icon to the right of the search bar in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So this is all the code for a website I'm making and I have a search bar in my nav section. I wanted to include an icon from Font Awesome and I've added this in there, but I can't seem to place it in the correct place, which is next to the search bar on the right. Is there any way I can fix this? Some help would be greatly appreciated :)

As follows is the Javascript, CSS and HTML code for the website.

```js
function AboutHover() {
  document.getElementById('about-button').firstElementChild.style.fontWeight = "bold";
}

function AboutNormal() {
  document.getElementById('about-button').firstElementChild.style.fontWeight = "normal";
}

function GalleryHover() {
  document.getElementById('gallery-button').firstElementChild.style.fontWeight = "bold";
}

function GalleryNormal() {
  document.getElementById('gallery-button').firstElementChild.style.fontWeight = "normal";
}

function ContactHover() {
  document.getElementById('contact-button').firstElementChild.style.fontWeight = "bold";
}

function ContactNormal() {
  document.getElementById('contact-button').firstElementChild.style.fontWeight = "normal";
}
```

```css
body, html{
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
   font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 1.5%;
}

header{
    background:rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header::after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear:both;
}

.logo{
    width: 9%;
    height: 5.4%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav{
    float: inline-end;
    overflow: auto;
}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 6.3%;
    padding-top: 1.8%;
    font-size: 112.5%;
    position: relative;
}

nav input[type=text]{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 2%;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: rgb(95, 62, 64);
    font-size: 112.5%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid 2px black;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

nav input::placeholder{
    color: rgb(95, 62, 64);
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

nav i{
    float: right;      
}

nav a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

nav a:hover{
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

nav a::before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0%;
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before{
    width: 100%;
}

.bg-one{
    background-image: url("bg-one.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position:relative;     
}


.transbox{
    padding: 0.8%;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border: 10px double rgb(240, 178, 182);
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 406.25%;
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0, .7); 
}

.first-block{
    height: 12%;
    background-color:rgb(241, 200, 203);
    text-align: center;
    border: 10px double white;
    padding-top: 1.6%;
    padding-bottom: 3.8%;
    vertical-align: auto;
}

h3{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 250%;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(199, 127, 131);
    font-weight: 500;
}

.bg-two{
    background-image: url("bg-two.jpg");    
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.about-box{
    width: 32%;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: rgba(241, 200, 203, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: 3.8%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1.35%;
}

h4{
    font-size: 312%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    color:rgb(126, 81, 83);
}

.about-box p, .gallery-box p, .contact-box p{
    font-size: 125%;
    text-align: center;
    color:rgb(95, 62, 64);
}

.about-box-two{
    width: 92%;
    height: 45%;
    background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.about-button{
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 21%;
    margin-left: 102%;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(126, 81, 83);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.about-button a, .gallery-button a, .contact-button a{
    font-size: 156.25%;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: rgb(126, 81, 83);
}

.far{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.bg-three{
    background-image: url("bg-three.jpg");    
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.gallery-box{
    width: 30%;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: rgba(241, 200, 203, .7);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: 65%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    
}

.gallery-box-two{
    width: 91%;
    height: 45%;
    background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 3.5%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1%;
}

.gallery-button{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30.55%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    display: block;
    padding: 1.2%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(126, 81, 83);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.bg-four{
    background-image: url("bg-four.jpg");    
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.contact-box{
    width: 36%;
    height: 35%;
    background-color: rgba(241, 200, 203, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 16%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.contact-box-two{
    width: 93%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 3.4%;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.contact-button{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 28.8%;
    margin-left: 630px;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(126, 81, 83);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.footer{ 
    height: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    h1{
        font-size: 312%;
    }

    a{
        font-size: 80%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
        <title>New York - The City That Never Sleeps</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f107c76e74.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
            <img src="nyc-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" >
                </ul>
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="bg-one">
            <div class="transbox">
                <h1>NEW YORK</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="first-block">
            <h3>Welcome to the city that never sleeps...</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-two">
            <div class="about-box">
                <h4>ABOUT</h4>
                <div class="about-box-two">
                    <p> Well-known for its attractive landscapes and environment, New York attracts more than 67 million visitors every year.
                        <br>Click on the button to explore New York's finest attractions and landmarks in the 'About' page!</br>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="about-button" id="about-button" onmouseover="AboutHover()" onmouseout="AboutNormal()">
                    <a href="#">ABOUT<i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:auto; height: 20px; background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203, .7);"></div>
        <div class ="bg-three">
            <div class="gallery-box">
                <h4>GALLERY</h4>
                <div class= "gallery-box-two">
                    <p>Take a peek into some first-hand images taken by tourists in New York. 
                        <br>Click on the button to discover New York's beautiful features...</br></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class= "gallery-button" id="gallery-button" onmouseover="GalleryHover()" onmouseout="GalleryNormal()">
                <a href="#">GALLERY<i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: auto; height: 20px; background-color: rgba(241, 200, 203, .7);"></div>
        <div class="bg-four">
            <div class = "contact-box">
                <h4>CONTACT</h4>
                <div class = "contact-box-two">
                    <p>To find out the places where you can experience the best of New York, click on the button!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "contact-button" id="contact-button" onmouseover="ContactHover()" onmouseout="ContactNormal()">
                <a href = "#">CONTACT<i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p> </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[What the header currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZxQk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but going off the code you already have, I will suggest just a few tweaks that should make this possible:

- Take the input out of the `<ul>` in your nav. Since it isn't in a `<li>` tag, it is actually invalid html to do it that way
- Put a `<div>` after the `<ul>` and place the `<input>` and the icon inside it
- Adjust the css so that the `float: right;` is on your `<div>` instead of on the `input` and `i` elements. Also move any spacing related styles onto the `div`

In the example below, I gave the new `div` a class of `.search` and moved some styles on to it from your `input`. I also removed the float from the icon style.

```js
function AboutHover() {
  document.getElementById('about-button').firstElementChild.style.fontWeight = "bold";
}

function AboutNormal() {
  document.getElementById('about-button').firstElementChild.style.fontWeight = "normal";
}

function GalleryHover() {
  document.getElementById('gallery-button').firstElementChild.style.fontWeight = "bold";
}

function GalleryNormal() {
  document.getElementById('gallery-button').firstElementChild.style.fontWeight = "normal";
}

function ContactHover() {
  document.getElementById('contact-button').firstElementChild.style.fontWeight = "bold";
}

function ContactNormal() {
  document.getElementById('contact-button').firstElementChild.style.fontWeight = "normal";
}
```

```css
body, html{
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
   font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 1.5%;
}

header{
    background:rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header::after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear:both;
}

.logo{
    width: 9%;
    height: 5.4%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav{
    float: inline-end;
    overflow: auto;
}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 6.3%;
    padding-top: 1.8%;
    font-size: 112.5%;
    position: relative;
}
nav .search{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
nav input[type=text]{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: rgb(95, 62, 64);
    font-size: 112.5%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid 2px black;    
}

nav input::placeholder{
    color: rgb(95, 62, 64);
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}


nav a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

nav a:hover{
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

nav a::before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0%;
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before{
    width: 100%;
}

.bg-one{
    background-image: url("bg-one.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position:relative;     
}


.transbox{
    padding: 0.8%;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border: 10px double rgb(240, 178, 182);
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 406.25%;
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0, .7); 
}

.first-block{
    height: 12%;
    background-color:rgb(241, 200, 203);
    text-align: center;
    border: 10px double white;
    padding-top: 1.6%;
    padding-bottom: 3.8%;
    vertical-align: auto;
}

h3{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 250%;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(199, 127, 131);
    font-weight: 500;
}

.bg-two{
    background-image: url("bg-two.jpg");    
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.about-box{
    width: 32%;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: rgba(241, 200, 203, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: 3.8%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1.35%;
}

h4{
    font-size: 312%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    color:rgb(126, 81, 83);
}

.about-box p, .gallery-box p, .contact-box p{
    font-size: 125%;
    text-align: center;
    color:rgb(95, 62, 64);
}

.about-box-two{
    width: 92%;
    height: 45%;
    background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.about-button{
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 21%;
    margin-left: 102%;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(126, 81, 83);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.about-button a, .gallery-button a, .contact-button a{
    font-size: 156.25%;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: rgb(126, 81, 83);
}

.far{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.bg-three{
    background-image: url("bg-three.jpg");    
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.gallery-box{
    width: 30%;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: rgba(241, 200, 203, .7);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: 65%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    
}

.gallery-box-two{
    width: 91%;
    height: 45%;
    background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 3.5%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1%;
}

.gallery-button{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30.55%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    display: block;
    padding: 1.2%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(126, 81, 83);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.bg-four{
    background-image: url("bg-four.jpg");    
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.contact-box{
    width: 36%;
    height: 35%;
    background-color: rgba(241, 200, 203, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 16%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.contact-box-two{
    width: 93%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 3.4%;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.contact-button{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 28.8%;
    margin-left: 630px;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(126, 81, 83);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.footer{ 
    height: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203);
    position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    h1{
        font-size: 312%;
    }

    a{
        font-size: 80%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
        <title>New York - The City That Never Sleeps</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f107c76e74.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
            <img src="nyc-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">

              <nav>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>

                  </ul>
                  <div class="search">
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
                      <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </div>
              </nav>

            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="bg-one">
            <div class="transbox">
                <h1>NEW YORK</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="first-block">
            <h3>Welcome to the city that never sleeps...</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-two">
            <div class="about-box">
                <h4>ABOUT</h4>
                <div class="about-box-two">
                    <p> Well-known for its attractive landscapes and environment, New York attracts more than 67 million visitors every year.
                        <br>Click on the button to explore New York's finest attractions and landmarks in the 'About' page!</br>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="about-button" id="about-button" onmouseover="AboutHover()" onmouseout="AboutNormal()">
                    <a href="#">ABOUT<i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:auto; height: 20px; background-color: rgb(241, 200, 203, .7);"></div>
        <div class ="bg-three">
            <div class="gallery-box">
                <h4>GALLERY</h4>
                <div class= "gallery-box-two">
                    <p>Take a peek into some first-hand images taken by tourists in New York. 
                        <br>Click on the button to discover New York's beautiful features...</br></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class= "gallery-button" id="gallery-button" onmouseover="GalleryHover()" onmouseout="GalleryNormal()">
                <a href="#">GALLERY<i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: auto; height: 20px; background-color: rgba(241, 200, 203, .7);"></div>
        <div class="bg-four">
            <div class = "contact-box">
                <h4>CONTACT</h4>
                <div class = "contact-box-two">
                    <p>To find out the places where you can experience the best of New York, click on the button!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "contact-button" id="contact-button" onmouseover="ContactHover()" onmouseout="ContactNormal()">
                <a href = "#">CONTACT<i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p> </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it now works, however, the positioning of the search bar is making the whole header size too big in terms of it's height.... is there a way to position it more towards the top so that the header height can be reduced?

Comment: I have inserted an image link underneath the original code to show what is now happening and explains my problem.

Comment: The problem is your `<ul>` is currently taking up the full width of the page, so the search field has no room to sit next to it and falls underneath. You can either set the `<ul>` css to `display: inline;` or mess around with `display: inline-block` and setting a width so it doesn't take up all the space/leaves enough room for your search field.

Comment: Ok I managed to fix it with some changes to the display section. Thank you so much again for the help! Literally saved my life